# how to pass the parameter 08-2019 in birt report

Tags: birt

[image]

how to pass the parameter 08-2019 in birt report I need to pass this month and year parameter which I marked

Answer (score 0):

You do that with query parameters. You first need to exchange the date string in the query with questions marks (?). For your example, this will be 5 question marks.

Edit the Dataset, change the query, and then click `Parameters` on the left. Important: you need to add a parameter for each single question mark **even if they all relate to the same value**. Parameters will be added to your query in order of definition. If you have more or less parameters than question marks in your query, an exception will be raised. So keep these synchronized.

As you do have a specific date format, do use `String` as parameter type. You can use a report parameter as a reference and pass that string dynamically (which is most likely what you want).

[image]